# android create calendar event with no reminders

Tags: android, events, calendar, notifications

I've set a method to add a calendar event as below, but I can't find how to disable reminders for it, as it is now the window appears with a 10 minutes reminder (notification) already set.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent ev = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    ev.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    ev.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    ev.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    ev.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, false);
    ev.putExtra("allDay", false);
    ev.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
    ev.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1");
    ev.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    ev.putExtra("title", "Daily goal!");
    ev.putExtra("description", sEvent);
    startActivity(ev)
```